# Python pandas to_csv causes OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("path/to/my/infile.csv")
df = df.sort_values(['distance', 'time'])
df.to_csv("path/to/my/outfile.csv")
```

This code reads from infile.csv which is a 3GB csv file successfully, sorts it and fails when trying to write to outfile.csv with the following error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3a5c8279658d> in <module>
----> 1 df.to_csv('/Users/joaomatos/Desktop/cluster22_sorted_training.csv',index=False)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   1743                                  doublequote=doublequote,
   1744                                  escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
-> 1745         formatter.save()
   1746 
   1747         if path_or_buf is None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py in save(self)
    164                                          encoding=encoding,
    165                                          compression=self.compression)
--> 166                 f.write(buf)
    167                 f.close()
    168                 for _fh in handles:

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

My question is why?

Comment: I think there is a "by" missing: df.sort_values(by=['distance', 'time'])

Comment: the sorting is working fine

Comment: Have you tried writing just a couple of rows? `df.head().to_csv("path/to/my/outfile.csv")`

Comment: yes, it works, which suggests it may be something related to file size

Comment: Maybe chunksize will help you: `df.head().to_csv("path/to/my/outfile.csv", chunksize=10000)`

Comment: @vercelli yes it occurred to be as well, but with no success :(

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3858) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/FPn60YCffbw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently this problem is caused by a known bug reported [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21643) associated with a previous version of pandas. All I had to do was `pip3 install --upgrade pandas` and then restart the computer.

Answer (score 20):

After exploring a lot of options, including the pandas library update to the latest version (1.2.4 as of today), changing the engine to "python" or "c", debugging, etc. I finally discovered what the issue was:

I had my **CSV files** stored in a folder that was **constantly being synchronized in real-time with OneDrive**.

YES! I discovered that the tray icon was becoming crazy and OneDrive was consuming resources at the same time I was doing algorithmic trading backtesting to my pet project. **I paused sync and then it never failed again!!**

I guess you can also exclude the folder from OneDrive or simply change the location where the CSVs are stored/written/accessed.

Comment: I had the same issue that randomly popped up, my code ran for most of the time and throw this error every once in a while. What you explained about sync Issue makes sense to me, is there a code to check if the file is in use wait till its done syncing and then start writing the code? Any other solution beside stopping the sync.

Answer (score 15):

I just had a similar issue and I was using back slash `\` which usually works in the past but this time turn out I had to use `/` instead, which is extremely weird but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (working on an external hard drive) it worked once I specified the absolute, rather than the relative, path.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by removing unusual characters contained in the timestamp that made up part of the filename.

Not working:

```
file_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
df.to_csv(file_name + '_' + file_timestamp + '.csv')
```

Working:

```
file_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
df.to_csv(file_name + '_' + file_timestamp + '.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

[One of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811910/python-pandas-to-csv-causes-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument/56602861#56602861) mentions to substitute `\` with `/`. This works with me as well, but it can be tedious. An alternative is to put an `r` in front of the string (like this: `r"my\string\"`), which tells the interpreter to treat the backslashes (`\`) as raw characters, instead of combining them with the next char to form a special character (e.g., `\n`, `\t`).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove any file in "path/to/my/" or try:

```
if not files_present:
    pd.to_csv(filename)
else:
    print 'WARNING: This file already exists!'
```

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

print(pd.**file**)  ----read directory of pands

loan_data=pd.read_csv("D:\Lib\site-packages\pandas\email-password.csv")

loan_data

[image]