# Adding a new directory to PyCharm project, where all csv's should be stored

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a program that should be able to work for anyone using it. The problem is that there is a lot of data csv documents involving this program. Therefore, I want to add code, so that whenever someone runs the code, it will create a directory in their project called 'downloaded-data'. The requested dataframes (df) should then be locally stored in this directory only on their computer. The idea is to allow several colleagues to use this code without everyone being overloaded with someone else's requested data.

The current code:

```
    dir_for_downloaded_data = "downloaded-data/"
    os.makedirs(dir_for_downloaded_data, exist_ok = True)

    # Folder for csvs
    dir_for_csvs = os.path.join(dir_for_downloaded_data, "csvs/")
    os.makedirs(dir_for_csvs, exist_ok=True)
    site = site.replace(",", " ")
    df.to_csv(os.path.join(dir_for_csvs,f"{site}-HaulTruckFillFactor-{beginning_date}-to-{last_date}.csv"),index=False)
    print("csv file created")
```

The error that I get is:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'downloaded-data/csvs/blablabla.csv'
```

How can I make this local data storage simple, to work on anyone's computer (assuming they have access to it, through git)

NOTE: This code is written after I successfully requested the data and made it a dataframe (df)

Comment: what are values for site, beginning_date, and last_date

Comment: I apologise profusely. In my introduction I stated 'The requested dataframes (df) should then be locally stored in this directory only on their computer'... when I meant 'The requested data/csv's that are already stored as dataframe (df) should then be locally stored in this directory only on their computer'  .. in otherwords, I request for a csv (that is stored as a dataframe) and I want that csv to be stored locally in 'downloaded-data', because I call for it later in the code.. Thanx, and again sorry for that

Comment: site = string (We have several sites/customers), begining_data = int (the date at which the data should start), last_date = int (the last date of requested data). There is a lot of code involving and translating this.. I believe that (for this specific problem) it is only needed in the csv name. Because the request method works, as is. Thanx @hchw

Comment: can you put the full traceback?

Comment: like the full error message, not just and edited final line

Comment: grab like the last 10 or so lines of the comment. im mainly interested to see at what line it was called and what the full csv name was

Comment: line 3228, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "C:\Users\Llewellyn\.virtualenvs\python-workflow-E_3SinfX\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 183, in save
    compression=self.compression,
  File "C:\Users\Llewellyn\.virtualenvs\python-workflow-E_3SinfX\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 399, in _get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'downloaded-data/csvs/byerwen.macmahon-HaulTruckFillFactor-2019-10-30 00:00:00-to-2019-11-29 00:00:00.csv'

Comment: will this do the trick?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811910/python-pandas-to-csv-causes-oserror-errno-22-invalid-argument